# Stackoverflow Jobs cannot navigate to other pages with results if you check the "Remote" checkbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

If "Remote" checkbox on https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/ is checked and there are 1+ pages of results, they cannot be access. When you press on the page number, it still displays the same results as on the 1st page.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs
2. Check "Remote"
3. Scroll down to the end of the page
4. Press any other page button (e.g. "2")

Expected result:

- 2nd page of the results for remote jobs should be displayed
- "2" should be highlighted instead of "1"

Actual behavior:

- 1st page of the results for remote jobs is displayed
- "1" is highlighted

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote-developer-jobs?sort=i&pg=2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this bug. A fix has been deployed, it should work as expected now.